# ¿En c# todos los tipos de datos son objetos?

Tags: c#, poo

Este es un tema que no termina de quedarme claro, buscando en sitios oficiales, foros y demás paginas. Los llamados "datos primitivos" en c# si es que hay ¿son todos objetos?.

Un ejemplo es el int internamente es un struct pero según la documentacion el struct es una implementación implícita de la clase System.ValueType entonces en creer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen dos categorias

[Tipos de valor (value type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

y los

[Tipos de referencia (Reference type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/490f96s2.aspx)

Queda claro que al derivar de algo mas todo es objetos, quizas la confusion que tienes es que los tipos por valor tambien puede instanciarse. Esto es asi porque cuando usas `int` en realidad es un alias de `System.Int32`.

Todos son objetos, pero no se comportan de la misma forma, cuando asignas un valor a una variable `int` al pasarlo a otra copiara su contenido, en cambio un tipo por referencia sera un puntero a la direccion en memoria.

Si cambias el valor asignado a un int no afectaras a las demas variables que hayas asignado con esta, mientas que si cambias un tipo por referencia si las afectara.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, lo que comentas me suena a que los  objetos caso **int**  son como en c++ el cual se manejan en la pila y su contenido se pasa por valor y no por referencia.

Comment: exacto es como c++, el int se asignan por valor